# Exponential congruence

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

Hi All am a bit stuck on some revision that I am trying to do.

Firstly (part a) I must calculate the inverse of 11 modulo 41, which I have done and believe it to be 15.

The next part is to: 
Now use your result from part (a) to find x where x^11 mod 42 = 10

I have been trying all sorts but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: How do you get 11 modulo 41 = 15?

Comment: My mistake, it is meant to be the inverse of 11 modulo 41!

Comment: Is the second part about mod 42, or mod 41?

Answer (score 3):

$4\cdot 11\equiv 3\pmod{41}$, hence $$8\cdot 11\equiv 6\pmod{41}$$
and by multiplying both sides by seven we get that $8\cdot 7\equiv 56\equiv 15\equiv 11^{-1}.$

By the Chinese theorem, $x^{11}\equiv 10\pmod{42}$ is equivalent to:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x^{11} &\equiv& 0\pmod{2},\\ x^{11} &\equiv& 1\pmod{3},\\x^{11}&\equiv& 3\pmod{7},\end{array}\right.$$
or to:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x &\equiv& 0\pmod{2},\\ x &\equiv& 1\pmod{3},\\x^{-1}&\equiv& 3\pmod{7},\end{array}\right.$$
and since the inverse of $3\pmod{7}$ is $5$, from:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x &\equiv& 0\pmod{2},\\ x &\equiv& 1\pmod{3},\\x&\equiv& 5\pmod{7},\end{array}\right.$$
we get the solution $x\equiv 40\equiv -2\pmod{42}$.

I cannot see how the inverse of $11\pmod{41}$ is involved here: $42$ is not a prime!

Comment: How does $x^{11}\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ result in $x^{-1}\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ ?

Comment: @eurphorix: $$ x^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{7} $$ as a consequence of Fermat's little theorem. Multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$.

Answer (score -4):

You are trying to compute $10^\frac{1}{11}$:

$10^\frac{1}{11}=10^{15}=(10^3)^5$.

But $10^3=1000\equiv 16\ (mod\ 41)$

So $(10^3)^5=16^5=16\cdot16^2\cdot16^2=16\cdot 100=16\cdot 18=288\equiv 7\ (mod\ 41)$ since $16^2\equiv10\ (mod\ 41)$, $100\equiv 18\ (mod\ 41)$, and $288\equiv7\ (mod\ 41)$.

So the solution to $x^{11}\equiv 10\ (mod\ 41)$ is $x=7$.

Comment: This isn't right. $7^{11}$ is not congruent 10 mod 41. Furthermore, the question is about mod 42, not mod 41.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Do you see where the mistake is?

Comment: Your first step doesn't hold. $x^{11}=10$ does not imply $x=10^{15}$